# How to write a relatively simple UPDATE query with two linked tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables, CARS and ORDERS.

Both have a mileage column, but the ORDERS table mileage column is blank on most rows.

I'd like to update the ORDERS.mileage with CARS.mileage. They are linked by a Vrm column.

Can someone help me with this query?

```
UPDATE orders
SET Mileage = (SELECT *
FROM `orders`
JOIN cars ON orders.Vrm = cars.Vrm
WHERE orders.mileage = '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JOIN` in the `UPDATE`'s `FROM` clause, rather than trying to use a subquery. Otherwise, you basically have the right idea.

```
UDPATE
  orders
  JOIN CARS ON orders.Vrm = cars.VRM
SET orders.Mileage = cars.mileage
WHERE orders.mileage = ''
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to run this in phpmyadmin on my machine (wamp) and it just says loading forever! Any way I can see the bottle neck?

Comment: @JamesWilson I had a typo in the `ON` clause, but that should just die outright.  How many rows are you updating?  Also, I added `SET orders.Mileage = cars.mileate`, whereas it started with `SET Mileage = cars.mileage` without the `orders` identifier.

Comment: Yeah I fixed all of those. There are 35 rows that need updating that have no mileage. There are 73000 rows in orders

Comment: @JamesWilson Do a `SELECT` version of this to see how long that takes.  `SELECT orders.*, cars.* FROM orders JOIN cars ON orders.Vrm = cars.Vrm WHERE orders.mileage = ''`  Any bottleneck would be either in `orders.mileage` lacking an index, or either `orders.Vrm, cars.Vrm` lacking an index.  Still, 73k isn't all that many rows.

Comment: Showing rows 0 - 29 ( 35 total, Query took 4.3036 sec)

Comment: Shall I just run this on the 3 columns you mention?: ALTER TABLE `table` ADD INDEX `product_id` (`product_id`)

Comment: @JamesWilson It's taking 4 seconds to select the values, it shouldn't be much longer than that to update them.  Are you sure PHPMyAdmin isn't timing out? Since you are running this on a local wamp box, you ought to try running it from a more bare client like the MySQL command line client.

Comment: Adding the indexes worked! The 4 second query ran in .100 seconds and the update query was similar!

Comment: @JamesWilson I'm not surprised the performance improved, but still surprised that phpmyadmin couldn't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1:

```
UPDATE orders
SET Mileage = (SELECT c.mileage
               FROM cars c 
               WHERE orders.Vrm = c.Vrm)
WHERE o.mileage = ''
```

Query 2:

```
UPDATE orders o
JOIN cars c ON o.Vrm = c.Vrm 
SET o.Mileage = c.mileage
WHERE o.mileage = ''
```

Some [sqlfidleexample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/717af/1)

Answer (score 0):

According [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), you should use this:

```
UPDATE orders, cars
SET orders.Mileage = cars.mileage
WHERE orders.Vrm = cars.Vrm AND orders.mileage = ''
```